# What are some questions that seem easy but aren't?

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics, big-list

I've only just started to study a degree in Mathematics and I find it extremely satisfying to have a seemingly easy question that is incredibly difficulty or tricky to work out. I've looked into heaps of competition exams (although they aren't really what I'm looking for - seeing that they don't usually seem easy). A good example are the so called 'Coffin Problems' (you can find some [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1556.pdf)).

I'm reaching out here to hear any original problems that fit into this category. Here's an example of mine:

> If $\sin \theta + \cos \theta + \tan \theta = -1$, find the values of $\sin \theta + \cos \theta - \tan \theta$ for $\theta$ not being a multiple of $\pi$.

From memory, one of the answers I got for that problem was $\sqrt{2}-1$, although I know that there are plenty of other answers.

Also, I appologise if this question does not belong on this site. This was the only site I thought of to ask a question like this. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493558/problems-with-difficult-to-see-solutions-that-are-nonetheless-easy-to-grasp

Comment: I think you would love _Proofs from the BOOK_...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["It looks straightforward, but actually it isn't"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415365/it-looks-straightforward-but-actually-it-isnt)

Answer (score 1):

There are some questions that are easy to comprehend, but for which we have no solution yet, period. I don't know if that is what you're looking for, or if you only want problems that *do* have a solution, but that hard to find, but here are some problems of the first kind:

**Goldbach Conjecture**: Every even number greater than $2$ is the sum of two prime numbers

E.g. $4=2+2; 6=3+3; 8=5+3$, etc.

We can comprehend this question immediately ... but no one knows the answer. We suspect it's true, but there is no proof yet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture

**Collatz Conjecture**: Take any whole positive number. If ity is even, divide by $2$. If odd, multiply by $3$ and add $1$. Keep doing this. The Collatz Conjecture is that if you keep doing this, you'll always at some point end up with 1.

Example: $7\to 22\to11\to34\to17\to52\to26\to13\to40\to20\to10\to5\to16\to8\to4\to2\to1$

Again, easy to comprehend, but no one knows if it's true or not.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture